# How to create a staticBitmap in a class outside the one that inherits of wx.Frame

Tags: python, class, inheritance, wxpython, python-2.7

My app has the following structure:

```
class GameWindow(wx.Frame):
    imageFile = r"C:\Users\Trufa\Desktop\pyll\img\ball.png"
    data = open(imageFile, "rb").read()
    stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
    bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(wx.ImageFromStream(stream))
    image = wx.Image(imageFile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.ball = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, image, (0, 0), (image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()))
    self.ball.Center()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = wx.App()
    GameWindow(None, title='Pyll')
    app.MainLoop()
```

This simplified version works as expected creating the ball and then centring it.

Now I have tried all sort of things but couldn't get around to how to solve the following: I want to create the ball and its methods in a separate class, like this:

```
class Ball:
    #Code to make the ball
    def move(self):
        self.ball.Center()
```

First of all is this a good approach o should I try to stay within the `GameWindow` class, I think I would benefit from abstracting the `Ball` concept as a class.

And anyway, how can this be done. I'm sure the Ball class has to inherit from someone but I'm not sure from whom.

I'm tried inheriting from `GameWindow` and from `wx.Frame` without any good results, but I'm not sure if I was doing something conceptuality wrong or was programming it wrong and was not able to do it for my lack of knowledge of programming classes and OO in general in python.

To sum up, I want something like this:

```
class Ball():#What should I inherit from?
    imageFile = r"C:\Users\Trufa\Desktop\pyll\img\ball.png"
    data = open(imageFile, "rb").read()
    stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
    bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(wx.ImageFromStream(stream))
    image = wx.Image(imageFile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.ball = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, image, (0, 0), (image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()))
    def move(self):
        self.ball.Center()
```

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is subclass wx.StaticBitmap. At least, that's my understanding of what you want to do. Here's a simple example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class Ball(wx.StaticBitmap):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, imageFile):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.StaticBitmap.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        image = wx.Image(imageFile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(image))
        self.Center()


########################################################################
class GamePanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.ball = Ball(self, "ball.png")
        sizer.Add(self.ball, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class GameWindow(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, title):
        """"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(400,400))
        panel = GamePanel(self)
        self.Show()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = wx.App()
    GameWindow('Pyll')
    app.MainLoop()
```